# How do I set relationship data as properties on a node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I've taken the leap from SQL to Neo4j. I have a few complicated relationships that I need to set as properties on nodes as the first step towards building a recommendation engine.

This Cypher query returns a list of categories and weights.

`MATCH (m:Movie {name: "The Matrix"})<-[:TAKEN_FROM]-(i:Image)-[r:CLASSIFIED_AS]->(c:Category) RETURN c.name, avg(r.weight)`

This returns

`{ "fighting": 0.334, "looking moody": 0.250, "lying down": 0.237 }`

**How do I set these results as key value pairs on the parent node?**

The desired outcome is this:

`(m:Movie { "name": "The Matrix", "fighting": 0.334, "looking moody": 0.250, "lying down": 0.237 })`

Also, I assume I should process my (m:Movie) nodes in batches so what is the best way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure how you're getting that output, that return shouldn't be returning both of them as key value pairs. Instead I would expect something like: `{"c.name":"fighting", "avg(r.weight)":0.334}`, with separate records for each pair.

You may need [APOC procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_map_functions) for this, as you need a means to set the property key to the value of the category name. That's a bit tricky, but you can do this by creating a map from the collected pairs, then use SET with += to update the relevant properties:

```
MATCH (m:Movie {name: "The Matrix"})<-[:TAKEN_FROM]-(:Image)-[r:CLASSIFIED_AS]->(c:Category) 
WITH m, c.name as name, avg(r.weight) as weight
WITH m, collect([name, weight]) as category
WITH m, apoc.map.fromPairs(category) as categories
SET m += categories
```

As far as batching goes, take a look at `apoc.periodic.iterate()`, it will allow you to iterate on the streamed results of the outer query and execute the inner query on batches of the stream:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
 "MATCH (m:Movie)
 RETURN m",
 "MATCH (m)<-[:TAKEN_FROM]-(:Image)-[r:CLASSIFIED_AS]->(c:Category) 
  WITH m, c.name as name, avg(r.weight) as weight
  WITH m, collect([name, weight]) as category
  WITH m, apoc.map.fromPairs(category) as categories
  SET m += categories",
{iterateList:true, parallel:false}) YIELD total, batches, errorMessages
RETURN total, batches, errorMessages
```